# How to have a C++ macro for debug, which can change its content

Tags: c++, macros

I want to use a macro for debugging purpose.
On the same time I want to be able to disable its content for pieces of code  that I think have been tested enough.
This without complex operations, without changing the code, and so on.

My first idea was to have in a file tested enough a structure like this one

```
...code that might need debugging...
#define DONT_DEBUG__
... code that I consider safe and tested...
#undef DONT_DEBUG__
...code that might need debugging...
```

To make this work, I thought to have my debug macro to be like this

```
#define checkpoint(...) \
    #ifdef DONT_DEBUG__ \
    {}
    #else \
    {... code for degubbing purpose... }\
    #endif
```

Of course, I sadly discovered that #ifdef can't be used within a #define.
And inverting the order of #define and #ifdef won't accomplish what I want to obtain, since it won't allow to switch the macro behavior, once defined.

Of course I might use a global variable, to contain the "DONT_DEBUG__" value, and make the macro act accordingly

```
static bool DONT_DEBUG__=true;
#define checkpoint(...) \
    {if (DONT_DEBUG__) \
    {}
    else \
    {... code for degubbing purpose... }}\
#endif
```

But adding a useless "if then else" construct in some cases -ie: very short, inlined functions which just make some arithmetic computations, that I want to check for not nan and not infinite return values in debug phase- would be a price to big to pay.

Is there any solution? A similar construct of #ifdef that can, indeed, be used within a macro?

Comment: There's `#ifndef`, which does precisely the opposite of `#ifdef`, or you can have `#if !DONT_DEBUG__`

Comment: There's [this](http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic) nice article which talks about making a very limited preprocessor `if` that can be used in macros. Maybe with a little experimenting you can use something like this? Might be a bit overkill though...

Comment: `DONT_DEBUG__` name is reserved to the language implementation. By defining it, the behaviour of the program will be undefined. You should choose another name for the macro.

Comment: To expand on @eeroika's comment, names with double underscores are always reserved.  Also, so are all leading underscores at file scope, or leading underscores followed by capital letters in any scope.  Easiest rule to remember: Don't use leading underscores or double-underscores (anywhere) in identifiers and you're always fine.

Comment: I would say that simple way would be to have multiple defines `checkpoint_feature_A`, `checkpoint_feature_B`... where each feature is define either as `checkpoint_debug` or `checkpoint_dont_debug`. If desired, you can add `DONT_DEBUG_feature_A` etc or some global define like `DONT_DEBUG_ANY` or `DEBUG_ALL` so that you have a more complete control.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis `Don't use leading underscores or double-underscores (anywhere) in identifiers and you're always fine` That list isn't exhaustive (the names from the standard library are also reserved, and some of those are macros), so technically following those doesn't necessarily imply that you're fine. But not following them means that you're always not fine.

Comment: @eerorika You are, of course, correct. I thought it was clear that my "rule" was referring to various use and placement of underscores, and nobody would read it to mean anything outside that context.

Answer (score 0):

- `#ifdef` can't be used inside macros
- There's unfortunately no way to emulate `#ifdef` completely within macros

But in case all you want to check for is if a macro is defined or not there's a neat workaround you can use: checking if the macro would expand or not.

The basic idea behind it is to concatenate the macro with some prefix - if the macro has been defined it will be expanded first - otherwise the macro name will be concated:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KKrP9j5K5)

```cpp
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_IMPL(a, b)
#define CONCAT_IMPL(a, b) a ## b

CONCAT(CHECK_,DEBUG) // => CHECK_DEBUG

#define DEBUG

CONCAT(CHECK_,DEBUG) // => CHECK_
```

Utilizing this we can define a macro `CHECK_DEBUG` so that when `DEBUG` is not defined it will be expanded further:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jdYK1Kj4o)

```cpp
#define IS_DEBUG_DEFINED() CHECK((CONCAT(CHECK_,DEBUG), 0, 1))
#define CHECK_DEBUG ~,~
#define CHECK(tuple) CHECK_IMPL tuple
#define CHECK_IMPL(a, b, c, ...) c

#define DEBUG
IS_DEBUG_DEFINED() // => 1
#undef DEBUG
IS_DEBUG_DEFINED() // => 0
```

- The basic idea here is that if `DEBUG` is not defined, then `CHECK_IMPL(~,~,0,1)` will end up be called (because `CHECK_DEBUG` expands to `~, ~`) (which results in `0`).
- But when `DEBUG` is defined then `CHECK_IMPL(CHECK_,0,1)` will be called (`DEBUG` got expanded before it got concatenated) (which results in `1`).

So this basically gives you an easy way to check if a macro is defined or not. Then you only need a basic [preprocessor if](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms#pattern-matching) to do something depening on wether or not the macro is defined:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vEoK4coo6)

```cpp
#define IIF(value) CONCAT(IIF_,value)
#define IIF_0(true_value, false_value) false_value
#define IIF_1(true_value, false_value) true_value

#define DO_SOMETHING() \
  IIF(IS_DEBUG_DEFINED())( \
    /* DEBUG is defined */ \
    printf("DEBUG IS DEFINED!"); \
  , \
    /* DEBUG is NOT defined */ \
    printf("NO DEBUGGING TODAY!"); \
  )


// Example:
#define DEBUG

DO_SOMETHING() // => printf("DEBUG IS DEFINED!");

#undef DEBUG

DO_SOMETHING() // => printf("NO DEBUGGING TODAY!");
```

---

There's one small caveat with that technique though, namely that the macro you want to test needs to expand to a valid preprocessor identifier. This is required because [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) requires the resulting token to be a valid identifier.

So as long as the macro to be tested expands to only letters, digits and underscores this will work.
Everything else will result in a preprocessor error.

Examples:

```cpp
// Those are ok:
#define DEBUG
#define DEBUG 123
#define DEBUG foobar
#define DEBUG 1a2b
// ...

// Those won't work: (preprocessor error)
#define DEBUG ()
#define DEBUG +
#define DEBUG a, b, c
// ...
```

But that shouldn't be a problem for most usecases.

---

Here's a full example for your `DONT_DEBUG__` macro:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5768Tb17o)

```cpp
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_IMPL(a, b)
#define CONCAT_IMPL(a, b) a ## b

#define IS_DONT_DEBUG_DEFINED() CHECK((CONCAT(CHECK_,DONT_DEBUG__), 0, 1))
#define CHECK_DONT_DEBUG__ ~,~
#define CHECK(tuple) CHECK_IMPL tuple
#define CHECK_IMPL(a, b, c, ...) c

#define IIF(value) CONCAT(IIF_,value)
#define IIF_0(true_value, false_value) false_value
#define IIF_1(true_value, false_value) true_value

#define DO_SOMETHING() \
  IIF(IS_DONT_DEBUG_DEFINED())( \
    /* DONT_DEBUG__ is defined */ \
    printf("NOT DEBUGGING TODAY!"); \
  , \
    /* DONT_DEBUG__ is NOT defined */ \
    printf("DO THE THING!"); \
  )

#define DONT_DEBUG__

DO_SOMETHING() // printf("NOT DEBUGGING TODAY!");

#undef DONT_DEBUG__

DO_SOMETHING() // printf("DO THE THING!");
```